# How to convert a string to an integer class within a python function?

Tags: python, string, integer, range

In a python function, I have defined two variables as letters.

```
def Vandermonde(x, d):
    x_0=-1
a = np.arange(d)
```

I am getting the error that "d"is not defined in a = np.arange(d). I suspect, but could be wrong, that this is because d is classified as a string not an integer.

I was expecting this to not matter in the code of the function where d is a variable. I know the code works (the rest of the code not shown does work on its own where d is defined as an integer before hand.
How do I get the error message to not appear when defining this as a function?

Comment: Indentation! Python defines scopes via indentations (among other things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation! Python functions (and their respective scopes) are defined via indentations.

```
def Vandermonde(x, d):
    x_0=-1
    a = np.arange(d)  # Note the indentation here
```

should fix the problem...

Comment: Scopes are defined by functions; indentation happens to be how you define the `def` statement. (Indentation used for other compound commands have no effect on scope.)

Comment: Indentation is used for parsing the scopes of `if`, `with`, and more. So this may be a "tomayto tomahto" scenario, but I prefer the way I described it.

Comment: Not really. The body of `if` et al. statements are indented, but no new scope is created. We're talking about variable scope, not "which compound statement is another statement nested in".

Comment: Ah. I meant "scope" in a more general sense. `with` for instance has a scope, with regards to a *specific* variable.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you use `with open(...) as f:`, for example, `f` remains defined *after* the `with` statement completes. The only "scope" involved is when the context manager's `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are called relative to the body of the `with` statement.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'm using the word scope too loosely, and should stick to the specific coding usage of the word. Does my edit make things better in your oppinion?